# How can I run start-client and start-server simultaneously?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, server

I am using webpack, and I tried to open my server by it. But when I tried `npm run start-server` after `npm run start-client`, it threw error: **Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use  :::3333 at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] at listenInCluster at Server.listen at C:￦PathToProject￦node_modules￦webpack-dev-server￦lib￦Server.js**.

**package.json**

```
   ...
   "scripts": {
     "start-client": "webpack && webpack-dev-server",
     "start-server": "node server.js"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "webpack": "^5.39.1",
     "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
     "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
   }
   ...
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const nodeExt = require("webpack-node-externals");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: './client.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(_dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExt()],
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    port: 3333
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
const PORT = 3333
const port = process.env.PORT || PORT;
const server = http.createServer();

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server start');
});
```

Comment: Why not just change the PORT in use in `server.js`?

Comment: I used the port = 3333 to use the server in localhost: 3333.